# Where is the hardcoded RTP video buffer size in stagefrightlib Android 2.3 Gingerbread?

Tags: android, buffer, rtp, rtsp, stagefright

**Where exactly is the default buffer size stored?**

I got as far as

```
void OMXCodec::setMinBufferSize() in media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp
```

I am interested in the **H263-1998/H263-2000** decoder if it makes any difference.